# partition key for cassandra db single node

Tags: cassandra, nosql, data-modeling

Partition key is used to distribute row to nodes. If I only use one single node, should I worry about the warning of comparing on partition key?

Moreover, in my user case, I need to query on partition key by both equation and comparison < >. Any suggestion on how to design the primary key?

Answer (score 0):

- If you ran Cassandra on a single node you loose almost all the advantages it has: scaling (both in throughput and volume) as much as you need, resiliency. For a dev/test server it is ok but if you are thinking about production 3 nodes is a minimum (to get proper consistency level).

You seem to need quick tutorials to get you going :

- [Fundamentals](https://www.datastax.com/learn/cassandra-fundamentals)
- [Data Modelling](https://www.datastax.com/learn/data-modeling-by-example) but also [DS220 on Datastax Academy](http://academy.datastax.com).

Comment: I think use single node nosql db is still valid case for some user cases. One user case is my business data model simply does not have such partition key logically.

Comment: In the above case, what would you be case for high-availablity? :thinking:

Answer (score 0):

Cédrick makes a good point. Your cluster should be at least 2-3 nodes with the replication factor set to the number of nodes. Then each node will still have all of the data, but the cluster will have some resiliency to hardware failure.

> should I worry about the warning of comparing on partition key?

Not really, no. Although if the cluster grows to the point where someday it is big enough where not all data exists on all nodes, you'll be glad that you *did* follow the standard Cassandra modeling advice.

> in my user case, I need to query on partition key by both equation and comparison < >. Any suggestion on how to design the primary key?

Without seeing the queries that you need to support, that's going to be difficult. I'd say that it's more of a question of whether or not this data set is actually going to grow beyond a size of 1 to 3 nodes.

If it is user data and it *will* grow, then I would find something to partition the users by. Something where it makes sense according to the business case. For example, if this was for employee data, and I knew that all result sets would be for employees in the same department, then perhaps department makes for a good partition key. Then I'd add user ID and user name to round out the rest of the PK:

```
PRIMARY KEY (department,user_id,user_name);
```

This way, you could easily support whatever operators were required on `user_id`.  Or, if `user_name` was more relevant, then `user_id` and `user_name` could be flipped in their order, with `user_id` there to ensure row uniqueness (two people in the same dept with the same name, but different IDs).

> only use one single node

On the other hand, if this dataset will not grow beyond the need for a single node, then my suggestion (*and I don't say this often*) would be to just use Postgres.  You'll save yourself a lot of headaches later on.